# How to view list of files in Google Drive?

Tags: ls, gmail, gvfs, google-drive

When I list directory components with

```
$ ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=address

1BzrSykm6X7BBm09yZ7Qcsj_5lL1dMtrN  1p55c8zr6M617qoFU8BopppxaLh0qJTd8
1eEWOjFJYcZNHj2elzQE7XoYnafUsUyGp  1pMlTX2iBAq7iYLN-zhhDtN32CyG4YlRB
1EklWWeRiyZdiWdIWtD6KZAtULZVSTa7C  1puzTh0qsXrSo0GagieSF2iME9drmBtki
1fbbsvQn4Wj_6tN2euKnOUK7IAu1hEJ3x  1RLdd0sHYWJUFEua1M2XuOw2O2GBEyw47
```

The filenames are unintelligible, but I can copy these files.

How can I get the filenames as I using the browser?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
gio list -d
```

More info here: https://medium.com/@naufhalrenjira/how-to-use-google-drive-in-your-ubuntu-20-04-f3f279cb9b02

Answer (score 1):

Try Open Drive client snap package (*odrive-unofficial*) on Ubuntu Software. It makes this easy because it's a GUI app. To install it from the terminal in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu type:

```
sudo snap install odrive-unofficial
```

Comment: Exactly the opposite. I want to be command line. 
  It's easy to copy the file to the inside drive and download file .

Answer (score 0):

You can download [**gdrive**](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive)

Make sure you click gdrive-linux-x64 if you have 64 bit system, or otherwise gdrive-linux-386
With gdrive you can do query to your google drive and download/upload files from terminal.